# Rails Helpers: Add a line break to the end of a content_tag within helper method

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following helper method for the `Contact` Model:

```
def list_offices_if_present(contact)
  if contact.locations.any?
    content_tag :span, "Works out of: #{contact.offices_list}" + tag(:br)
  end
end
```

Here is that method definition called within that `content_tag`:

```
#models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def offices_list
    offices_names = []
    locations.each{|location|  office_names << location.office_name}
    return office_names.join(", ")
  end
end
```

I call this helper like this:

```
<p>
  <%= list_offices_if_present(@contact) %>
  <%= list_phone_if_present(@contact)   %>
<p>
```

The issue is that the `<br>` tag is rendering out as text, and not an actual line break, like this:

```
Works out of: Some Location <br /> Phone: 402-555-1234
```

How do I add a line break to the end of a content_tag within a helper method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
content_tag(:span, "Works out of: #{contact.offices_list}" + raw("<br>"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails automatically escapes html entities, you can use:

```
content_tag :span, "Works out of: #{contact.offices_list}".html_safe + tag(:br)
```

Comment: Thanks!  May I ask why `html_safe` is necessary?

Comment: @Neil: after applying this method no additional escaping  will be performed, so raw html will be rendered instead of escaped string. I.e. `<span>Works out of: <...> <br /></span>` instead of `<span>Works out of: <...> &lt;br /&gt;</span>`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the following line of code

```
content_tag :span, "Works out of: #{contact.offices_list}" + tag(:br)
```

is executed as

```
content_tag(:span, "Works out of: #{contact.offices_list}" + tag(:br))
```

Notice `tag(:br)` is concatenated with `"Works out of: #{contact.offices_list}"` as second argument.

To fix it, add an explicit pair of parenthesis like this:

```
content_tag(:span, "Works out of: #{contact.offices_list}") + tag(:br)
```